# How to properly find an element through Selenium-WebDriver for input purposes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to create a program to automate certain downloads, however, when using Selenium-WebDriver, I find I can't seem to find the element needed to log in. I have located the correct element, however actually using the WebDriver#findElement() is giving me issues.

```
<input id="form-username" class="form-field" form="popup-login" type="text" name="username" value="" tabindex="1" autofocus="">
```

I've been trying different By methods, however none of them work, along with different ID's, albeit to no avail.

I have checked other posts, but none of them seem to fit as they are just retrieving information from specific points in the HTML like a String, where I want to input information into it.

```
public void start(String usernameInfo, String passwordInfo) {
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.nexusmods.com");

    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("form-username"));
    username.sendKeys(usernameInfo);
    username.submit();

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("form-password"));
    password.sendKeys(passwordInfo);
    password.submit();

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

The output log can be viewed here: https://hastebin.com/zuvebosaha.nginx

UPDATE:
Tried ChromeDriver, and found the following code (modified for my use)

```
public void start(String usernameInfo, String passwordInfo) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\veeay\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe"); //add chrome driver path (System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.drive",chrome driver path which you downloaded)

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // create object of ChromeDriver

    driver.manage().window().maximize(); // maximize the browser window

    driver.get("https://www.nexusmods.com/"); //enter url

    driver.findElement(By.id("form-username")).sendKeys(usernameInfo); //type textbox's id or name or any locater along with data in sendkeys

    driver.findElement(By.id("form-password")).sendKeys(passwordInfo);

    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000); //used thread for hold process
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.quit(); //for close browser
}
```

resulting in the following: https://hastebin.com/iliyuvucok.cs

UPDATE 2: Oddly enough, now that I actually post the question, I'm doing good. Now I can do everything except select the sign-in button.

```
public void start(String usernameInfo, String passwordInfo) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\veeay\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe"); //add chrome driver path (System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.drive",chrome driver path which you downloaded)

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // create object of ChromeDriver

    driver.manage().window().maximize(); // maximize the browser window

    driver.get("https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Widgets/LoginPopUp?url=%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2F"); //enter url

    driver.findElement(By.id("form-username")).sendKeys(usernameInfo); //type textbox's id or name or any locater along with data in sendkeys

    driver.findElement(By.id("form-password")).sendKeys(passwordInfo);

    driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in-button")).click();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000); //used thread for hold process
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.quit(); //for close browser
}
```

apparently the sign-in button is not interactable https://hastebin.com/ahuvezoxat.cs

Comment: Are you in a corporate network? At my work Selenium is blocked. Does retrieving other values work?

Comment: @JoschJava no, I am currently at my home

Comment: it might help to post the html for the entire form.  The submit button may not be clickable until the form's input fields are validated or filled out... so a wait for expected condition could be necessary.  When you first hit the form can you click submit manually?

Answer (score 0):

Added explicit wait and it works:

```
package vee;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class Vee {

        @Test
        public void start() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\selenium-tests\\GCH_driver\\chromedriver.exe");

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            // new explicit wait
            WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

            driver.get("https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Widgets/LoginPopUp?url=%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2F");

            // using explicit wait
            webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("sign-in-button")));

            driver.findElement(By.id("form-username")).sendKeys("some name");
            driver.findElement(By.id("form-password")).sendKeys("some password");

            // print true or false by the button state
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in-button")).isEnabled());

            driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in-button")).click();

            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 4301
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1560240089.419][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 75.
Čer 11, 2019 10:01:31 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
true
```

Maybe when repeating test, recaptcha pops up and disables the button.